# wordpress convert query string url to slash using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

I am trying to convert my url it query string to slash using htaccess but its not wokring.its a wordpress as a cms

Here is what i have done

```
http://mycouserweb.co.au/courses?month=02&cyear=2018
to
http://mycouserweb.co.au/courses/month/05/cyear/2017
```

My htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^courses/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ courses?month=$1&cyear=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: That is because WordPress overwrites `.htaccess`. You need to change the way your links display through WordPress. You can do this by going into your settings and changing the settings to your permalinks.

Comment: but that will affect other post and pages and change their structure as well if i change it in permalinks